# AWS SNS how to add line breaks in message

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send SNS messages via CLI in json format.

```
aws sns publish --cli-input-json "{\"TopicArn\":\"xxx\",\"Message\":\"first line\n second line\",\"Subject\":\"Empty subject\"}"
```

But the \n doesn't work. Neither is "\r\n" or "\n". I think the string is escaped by SNS so \n doesn't work. Does anyone know how to send a message of 2 lines?(Sending 2 messages is not an option) Appreciate your advice!

Comment: Can you enclose it with single quote and try? `\"first line'\n' second line\"`

Comment: No single quotes don't work :)

Comment: Your CLI command works perfectly without any change. I just sent an SNS and see two lines in my email. What shell are you using?

Comment: helloV thanks for pointing that out! Actually I invoked the command in the string format, in a minor language that few people use. In that case I must have made a mistake in how to escape within the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `\\n` is actually what you are looking for. I've just tested it by sending push notifications to my device through AWS SNS.

So your message should look like this:

```
aws sns publish --cli-input-json "{\"TopicArn\":\"xxx\",\"Message\":\"first line\\nsecond line\",\"Subject\":\"Empty subject\"}"
```

Note, you should not leave the white space after the line break symbol, otherwise, your new line would start with that space.

Answer (score 3):

aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:0123456789012:my-topic" --message file://message.txt

message.txt is a text file containing the message to publish:

Hello World
Second Line

Putting the message in a text file allows you to include line breaks
.

Answer (score 1):

This worked out for me:

```
"first line&#10;second line"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am publishing messages using the email protocol using the NodeJs `aws-sdk`. In order for exceptions to appear correctly, I needed to replace both `\n` and `\\n`, and to appease both windows and mac clients, used `\r\n`.

```js
message.replace(/\n|\\n/g, '\r\n')
```

---

For anyone who needs full code, this is how I am handling errors in typescript

```js
public prepareMessage(header: string, error: any) {
    const data = (error instanceof Error)
        ? JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error), 2)
        : JSON.stringify(error, null, 2);

    const replaceNewlines = (str: string) => str?.replace(/\n|\\n/g, '\r\n') || '';

    return `${replaceNewlines(header)}\r\n${replaceNewlines(data)}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

four backslash 
works for me

using Aws SNS with Firebase

EX: backslashbackslashbackslashbackslash+n

Answer (score 0):

After testing all suggested answers, here's what worked in my case (running from a python lambda function, publishing from boto3 sns client):

This created 2 new lines: `message.replace('\n', '\r\n')`

This created 1 new line: `message.replace('\n', '\r')`

**Example:**

```
message = message.replace('\n', '\r').replace('\t', '    ')

# Sending the notification...
snsclient.publish(
    TargetArn=SNS_EMAIL_ALERTS_ARN,
    Subject=f'{filter_name} Alert: ({lambda_func_name[3]})',
    Message=message
)
```