# Python boto3 SNS email formatting (each string in new line)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

How to print each string in a new line in an email using AWS SNS service.

If I print a message in Python output all strings is in new lines:

```
Started copying.. snapshot_id: snap-000000aeaada0000 from: region_src to: region_dst with new snapshot_id: new_snapshot_id
Started copying.. snapshot_id: snap-000000aeaada0001 from: region_src to: region_dst with new snapshot_id: new_snapshot_id
```

but in an email it is all in one line:

```
Started copying.. snapshot_id: snap-05b3834aeaada5a02 from: region_src to: region_dst with new snapshot_id: new_snapshot_id Started copying.. snapshot_id: snap-012d3db747de08d1f from: region_src to: region_dst with new snapshot_id: new_snapshot_id
```

```
import boto3

region_src = 'us-east-1'
sns_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000099:AWS_LAMBDA_NOTIFICATIONS"

def copy_snapshot_src_to_dst(snapshot_id):
    message = ("Started copying.. snapshot_id: " + str(snapshot_id) + " from: " + "region_src" + " to: " + "region_dst" + " with new snapshot_id: " + "new_snapshot_id")
    #print(message)

    return message

def lambda_handler():
    snapshots_id = [('snap-000000aeaada0000', [{'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'}, {'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}, {'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'}]), ('snap-000000aeaada0001', [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'}, {'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'}, {'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}, {'Key': 'aws:backup:source-resource', 'Value': 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'}])]
    message = ""

    for i in snapshots_id:
        snapshot_id = i[0]
        message += copy_snapshot_src_to_dst(snapshot_id) + '\n'
    print(message)
    send_sns(message)

def send_sns(message):
    if sns_arn:
        print("Sending SNS alert")
        sns = boto3.client("sns", region_name=region_src)
        response = sns.publish(
            TargetArn=sns_arn,
            Subject=("AWS LAMBDA NOTIFICATION"),
            Message=(message)
        )


lambda_handler()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `'\n'` by `".\n"` and after that in an email - each string is in a new line.

Comment: Found the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks) for others interested.

Based on that link, I used "\t\n" which works just as well and doesn't leave you with the visible period.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this: [AWS SNS how to add line breaks in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787953/aws-sns-how-to-add-line-breaks-in-message)

An option to consider is using SES to send email instead.  See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email.    Then you could send an email with HTML formatting, which makes it easy to use a table or break tags to format things:

```
client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')    
response = client.send_email(
Source='string',
Destination={
    'ToAddresses': [
        'string',
    ],
    'CcAddresses': [
        'string',
    ],
    'BccAddresses': [
        'string',
    ]
},
Message={
    'Subject': {
        'Data': 'string',
        'Charset': 'string'
    },
    'Body': {
        'Text': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'string'
        },
        'Html': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'string'
        }
    }
},
ReplyToAddresses=[
    'string',
],
ReturnPath='string',
SourceArn='string',
ReturnPathArn='string',
Tags=[
    {
        'Name': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
],
ConfigurationSetName='string'
```

)

Per "How is Amazon SES different from Amazon SNS?" at https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/

> "Amazon SES is for applications that need to send communications via
>   email. Amazon SES supports custom email header fields, and many MIME
>   types.
>
> By contrast, Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) is for
>   messaging-oriented applications, with multiple subscribers requesting
>   and receiving "push" notifications of time-critical messages via a
>   choice of transport protocols, including HTTP, Amazon SQS, and email.
>   The body of an Amazon SNS notification is limited to 8192 characters
>   of UTF-8 strings, and isn't intended to support multimedia content."